# Can stress tensor be defined on feature edges?

Tags: stresses, solid-mechanics, deformation, traction

Assume a rod is being extruded out of a cylinder by pushing the cylinder into a hole (See Figure below).
**Do the feature edges (or corners in 2D) cause the traction (the surface force) to be discontinuous?**
**Can we define the stress tensor at the corners?** [image]

Answer (score 1):

The stress does not make sense at absolutely sharp corners. In reality, the corners will have some radii on which actual stress/strain will depend.